# Не получается взять текст из QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Прикрепил к изменению текста QTextEdit

```
void MainWindow::on_MaxYtextEdit_textChanged()
{
    QString test = ui->MaxXtextEdit->toPlainText();
}
```

Поставил точку останова, и почему-то считывается с QTextEdit "".

Comment: Где точку поставили?

Comment: Как оказалось, дело в типе переменных. Почему-то QString оставляет недоступными свои поля в поле отладки. Если задать static, тогда можно просмотреть значение переменной. Вот в чём проблема была.

Answer (score 0):

Воспроизвел Ваш код, вставил печать (`qDebug()`) и текст печатается без проблем:

```
void MainWindow::on_textEdit_textChanged()
{
    qDebug() << ui->textEdit->toPlainText();
}
```

Comment: Спасибо что предложили так просмотреть, иначе бы и дальше думал, что не правильно захватываю значение. Благодаря этому понял, что если я хочу в меню отладки просмотреть значение переменной Qstring, то надо расширить её поле видимости.